# How can I unscale and understand glmnet coefficients while using tidymodels?

Tags: r, glmnet, tidymodels, regularized

I'm a bit confused with how I should interpret the coefficients from the elastic net model that I'm getting through `tidymodels` and `glmnet`. Ideally, I'd like to produce unscaled coefficients for maximum interpretability.

My issue is that I'm honestly not sure how to unscale the coefficients that the model is yielding because I can't quite figure out what's being done in the first place.

It's a bit tricky for me to post the data one would need to reproduce my results, but here's my code:

```
library(tidymodels)
library(tidyverse)

# preps data for model
myrecipe <- mydata %>%
  recipe(transactionrevenue ~ sessions + channelgrouping + month + new_user_pct + is_weekend) %>%
  step_novel(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  step_dummy(month, channelgrouping, one_hot = TRUE) %>%
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_normalize(sessions, new_user_pct) %>%
  step_interact(terms = ~ sessions:starts_with("channelgrouping") + new_user_pct:starts_with("channelgrouping"))
  
# creates the model
mymodel <- linear_reg(penalty = 10, mixture = 0.2) %>%
  set_engine("glmnet", standardize = FALSE)

wf <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(myrecipe)

model_fit <- wf %>%
  add_model(mymodel) %>%
  fit(data = mydata)
  
# posts coefficients
tidy(model_fit)
```

If it would help, here's some information that might be useful:

The variable that I'm really focusing on is "sessions."
In the model, the coefficient for sessions is `2543.094882`, and the intercept is `1963.369782`. The penalty is also `10`.

The unscaled mean for sessions is `725.2884` and the standard deviation is `1035.381`.

I just can't seem to figure out what units the coefficients are in and how/if it's even possible to unscale the coefficients back to the original units.

Any insight would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tidy()` on a lot of different components of a workflow. The default is to the `tidy()` the **model** but you can also get out the recipe and even recipe steps. This is where the information it sounds like you are interested in is.

```r
library(tidymodels)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip
data(bivariate)

biv_rec <- 
   recipe(Class ~ ., data = bivariate_train) %>%
   step_BoxCox(all_predictors())%>%
   step_normalize(all_predictors())

svm_spec <- svm_linear(mode = "classification")
biv_fit <- workflow(biv_rec, svm_spec) %>% fit(bivariate_train)

## tidy the *model*
tidy(biv_fit)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   term  estimate
#>   <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 A       -1.15 
#> 2 B        1.17 
#> 3 Bias     0.328

## tidy the *recipe*
extract_recipe(biv_fit) %>%
   tidy()
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   number operation type      trained skip  id             
#>    <int> <chr>     <chr>     <lgl>   <lgl> <chr>          
#> 1      1 step      BoxCox    TRUE    FALSE BoxCox_ZRpI2   
#> 2      2 step      normalize TRUE    FALSE normalize_DGmtN

## tidy the *recipe step*
extract_recipe(biv_fit) %>%
   tidy(number = 1)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   terms  value id          
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <chr>       
#> 1 A     -0.857 BoxCox_ZRpI2
#> 2 B     -1.09  BoxCox_ZRpI2

## tidy the other *recipe step*
extract_recipe(biv_fit) %>%
   tidy(number = 2)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   terms statistic   value id             
#>   <chr> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>          
#> 1 A     mean      1.16    normalize_DGmtN
#> 2 B     mean      0.909   normalize_DGmtN
#> 3 A     sd        0.00105 normalize_DGmtN
#> 4 B     sd        0.00260 normalize_DGmtN
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

You can [read more about tidying a recipe here](https://www.tmwr.org/recipes.html#tidy-a-recipe).